# c++ using std::lower_bound to find element in array by 2 parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, comparator, lower-bound

I have a problem using `lower_bound` to find element in array by 2 parameters.

I have a

```
struct person{
    public:
    person(const std::string CITY, const std::string ADDRESS, const std::string REGION, const unsigned ID, std::string PARENT = ""): m_city(CITY), m_addr(ADDRESS), m_region(REGION), m_id(ID), m_parent(PARENT) {}

    std::string m_city;
    std::string m_addr;
    
    std::string m_region;
    unsigned m_id;
    
    std::string m_parent;

};
```

from this structs there is a `std::vector<person>`

How can I find exact person using `lower_bound` in `vector` which is already sorted by Region?

My approach works the worst way. Most of the time it doesn't find anything.

```
auto iteratorRegion = findPerson(m_sortedByRegion, candidatePerson);

std::vector<person>::iterator findPerson(std::vector<Person>& ARRAY, const person& candidatePerson) const {
    auto iterator = std::lower_bound(ARRAY.begin(), ARRAY.end(), candidatePerson, cityAdressComparator);    if (iterator != ARRAY.end() && iterator->m_city == candidatePerson.m_city && iterator->m_addr == candidatePerson.m_addr) {
        return iterator;
    }
    auto iterator2 = std::lower_bound(ARRAY.begin(), ARRAY.end(), candidatePerson, regionIDComparator);     if (iterator2 != ARRAY.end() && iterator2->m_region == candidatePerson.m_region && iterator2->m_id == candidatePerson.m_id) {
        return iterator2;
    }
    return ARRAY.end(); 
}
```

All comparators looks like this inside:

```
if (!(realEstateL.m_city == realEstateR.m_city))
{
    return realEstateL.m_city < realEstateR.m_city;
}
return realEstateL.m_addr < realEstateR.m_addr;
```

Comment: Totally unrelated Personal Opinion: Flip the logic of the comparators around. If cities are the same, compare addresses. Otherwise compare cities. People's brains tend to process the flow better without the not.

Comment: If it's sorted by region, then perform binary search (lower_bound/equal_range) by region, then on the found region (I'm assuming you're using equal_range) perform another search, say by city **provided the regions are sorted by city**.

Comment: The input array must be sorted according to your comparator predicate. If it is not sorted, the behaviour is undefined. Is your data sorted with respect to `cityAdressComparator`? Will `std::is_sorted(..., cityAdressComparator)` return `true`?

Comment: Unrelated: Having both a `person` and a `Person` type is going to cause confusion. Please show a [mre] that we can compile as-is.

Comment: I see to usages of `lower_bound` with two different comparators: `cityAdressComparator` and `regionIDComparator` with same array value. This means that at least one of cases your data are sorted in different way then used comparator function. Range must be sorted with same comparation function as one fed to `lower_bound`.

Answer (score -1):

std::lower_bound is typically used to find the first element that is not less than the given value in a sorted range. Since you want to find an exact person based on two parameters (Region and ID), you may need to use a custom comparator function to achieve this.

In below example, the comparePerson function compares two person objects first by m_region and then by m_id. This custom comparator is then used with std::sort to sort the vector by region. Finally, std::lower_bound is used with the same custom comparator to find the exact person in the sorted vector.

Here's how you can use std::lower_bound with a custom comparator to find the exact person in the sorted vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct person {
    public: person(const std::string CITY, const std::string 
    ADDRESS, const std::string REGION, const unsigned ID, 
    std::string PARENT = ""): m_city(CITY), m_addr(ADDRESS), 
    m_region(REGION), m_id(ID), m_parent(PARENT) {}

    std::string m_city;
    std::string m_addr;

    std::string m_region;
    unsigned m_id;
    
    std::string m_parent;

    };

// Custom comparator function
bool comparePerson(const person& p1, const person& p2) 
{
    if (p1.m_region == p2.m_region)
    {
        return p1.m_id < p2.m_id; // If regions are the same, 
        compare by ID
    } 
    else
    {
        return p1.m_region < p2.m_region; // Otherwise, compare by 
         region
    }
 }

int main() {
    std::vector<person> persons = {
        {"CityA", "AddressA", "RegionA", 1},
        {"CityB", "AddressB", "RegionA", 2},
        {"CityC", "AddressC", "RegionB", 3}
    };

    // Sort the vector by region using custom comparator
        std::sort(persons.begin(), persons.end(), comparePerson);

    // Define the person to search for  
        person targetPerson("", "", "RegionA", 2); 
    // Searching for person in RegionA with ID 2

    // Find the person using lower_bound with custom comparator
        auto it = std::lower_bound(persons.begin(), persons.end(), 
        targetPerson, comparePerson);

        if (it != persons.end() && it->m_region == 
         targetPerson.m_region && it->m_id == targetPerson.m_id) 
          {
           std::cout << "Person found: " << it->m_city << " " << it- 
           >m_addr << std::endl;
          } 
        else {
           std::cout << "Person not found!" << std::endl;
          }
          return 0;
     }
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Not the down voter but there is a much better way to compare multiple fields at the same time now.  You can use `std::tie` to get a tuple that has an `operator <` that already "does the right thing".  That gives you `bool comparePerson(const person& p1, const person& p2) { return std::tie(p1.region, p1.id) < std::tie(p2.region, p2.id); }`

Comment: If you need to sort data before searching (takes `O(NlogN)` time) it's better to just use linear search (take `O(N)` time).